# How to download Road map dataset of previous 20years

Tags: geospatial

I want to download the **Road map** dataset of the previous 20years. How can I find the data and access that? I prefer Google Road map data.

Comment: I guess google data are far from truly "open" unfortunately...

Comment: There are other questions on OD.SE that reference open street map, not sure if there is one that answers your question with regard to